# Setting up nginx reverse proxy for jfrog artifactory and Jenkins

Tags: nginx, jenkins, docker-compose, artifactory

I am trying to set up a homeserver with Jenkins and Jfrog Artifactory OSS using docker-compose and Nginx as a reverse proxy.

The docker host has "homeserver" as hostname and my goal is to reach the Jenkins over http://homeserver/jenkins and artifactory over http://homeserver/artifactory.

While setting this up for Jenkins was no problem, I can't get artifactory to run as I want it to.

My docker-compose.yml is as follows:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
        reverseproxy:
                image: nginx
                container_name: homeserver-reverse-proxy
                ports:
                        - "80:80"
                        - "443:443"
                volumes:
                        - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

        jenkins:
                image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
                container_name: homeserver-jenkins
                environment:
                        - JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins"

        artifactory:
                image: docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest
                container_name: homeserver-artifactory
                volumes:
                        - artifactory-data:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
                ports:
                        - "8081:8081"
                        - "8082:8082"

volumes:
        artifactory-data:
```

I started off with the following nginx configuration:

```
events {}
http {
    upstream jenkins {
        server homeserver-jenkins:8080;
    }

    server {
        server_name homeserver;

        location /jenkins {
            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_pass http://jenkins;
            proxy_read_timeout 90;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_request_buffering off;
        }

        rewrite ^/$ /ui/ redirect;
        rewrite ^/ui$ /ui/ redirect;

        location / {
            if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
                set $http_x_forwarded_proto $scheme;
            }

            chunked_transfer_encoding on;
            client_max_body_size 0;

            proxy_read_timeout 2400s;
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
            proxy_pass http://homeserver-artifactory:8082;
            proxy_next_upstream error timeout non_idempotent;
            proxy_next_upstream_tries 1;
            proxy_set_header X-JFrog-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            location ~ ^/artifactory/ {
                proxy_pass http://homeserver-artifactory:8081;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This lets me access Jenkins as intended over http://homeserver/jenkins.
Artifactory is running (and accessible) with this configuration, but only directly at `/`.
Note that the parts for artifactory are exactly what the [Jfrog website](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuring+NGINX) suggests as configuration. 
That is not what I want, though.

In order to switch artifactory to http://homeserver/artifactory I see two possible options:

- Configure artifactory to include an URL prefix (like I configured Jenkins with the `JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins"`. However I could not figure out how to do this. The artifactory system.yml lets me configure the ports, but not the URL. Setting the Base URL over the web interface does not seem to work either, it just affects the redirected URLs and generated links (precisely at is stated in the tooltip of the website).
- Change the nginx configuration and rewrite the request URIs. I tried, but it just doesn't work as I hoped it would.

Here is what I tried for the second option:

```
events {}
http {
    upstream jenkins {
        server homeserver-jenkins:8080;
    }

    server {
        server_name homeserver;

        location /jenkins {
            # rewrite ^/jenkins(.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_pass http://jenkins;
            proxy_read_timeout 90;

            # proxy_redirect http://homeserver-jenkins:8080
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_request_buffering off;
        }

        rewrite ^/jfrog/$ /jfrog/ui/ redirect;
        rewrite ^/jfrog/ui$ /jfrog/ui/ redirect;

        location /jfrog/ {
            if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
                set $http_x_forwarded_proto $scheme;
            }
            rewrite ^/jfrog(.*)$ $1 break;

            chunked_transfer_encoding on;
            client_max_body_size 0;

            proxy_read_timeout 2400s;
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
            proxy_pass http://homeserver-artifactory:8082;
            proxy_next_upstream error timeout non_idempotent;
            proxy_next_upstream_tries 1;
            proxy_set_header X-JFrog-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            location ~ ^/artifactory/ {
                proxy_pass http://homeserver-artifactory:8081;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I already tried here to change the location from http://homeserver/artifactory to http://homeserver/jfrog to avoid clashes with the nested `location` block - don't know if that's important or not.

When trying to run this configuration, I get a lot of error messages from my reverseproxy like

"GET /ui/css/chunk-vendors.4485dbea.css HTTP/1.1" 404 154

and the Jfrog logo bitmap in the loading screen does not show, and neither does the website itself load correctly.

After checking the network traffic with firefox it seems to me that the problem comes from the `<link/>` elements in the HTML document which is loaded when visiting http://homeserver/jfrog/ui/. 
For example the CSS which led to the error message above comes from:

```
<link href="/ui/css/chunk-vendors.4485dbea.css" rel="preload" as="style">
```

Firefox then tries to load http://homeserver/ui/css/chunk-vendors.4485dbea.css. This does not work, the correct URL would be http://homeserver/jfrog/ui/css/chunk-vendors.4485dbea.css.